# how to perform mathematical operations in django template

Tags: html, django, list, for-loop, django-templates

i want to print the value of current item in list(which is a integer) and its successor(not the list item) but the actual integer successor) at the same time..i am using

```
{% for i in hour %}{{ i }}-{{i+1}}{% endfor %}
```

but this gives me an error of "Could not parse the remainder: '+1' from 'i+1'"

Comment: That is a view/controller function, it doesn't belong in the template, which is why it is not supported natively.

Comment: Could we maybe see your ```views.py```. So I can see exactly what ```hour``` is and what you are actually trying to display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `{{ i }}-{{ i|add:"1" }}`

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are three approaches:

1. Change to a different templating language that allows cleaner logic (Mako I believe though my knowledge is out of date)
2. Install a third party django package that allows you to do math in templates.
3. Create a template tag that accepts a value (i), does the calculation you want, and returns that value.

#3 is the one I would suggest.